# Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate, for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, ubuntu-20.04

After Upgrading to Ubuntu-20.04 I am unable to install pgadmin4.
Also, any other version of pgadmin is not working.

It is showing below error:

```
Package pgadmin4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pgadmin4' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package pgadmin4-apache2
```

In my "pgdg.list" file which can be accessed from below command

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

I have:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It's so disappointing that a key tool I use does not work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: it's not added in debiean repository. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230350/cant-install-pgadmin-4-on-20-04-lts

Answer (score 10):

You must create the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` file and add the line:

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ focal-pgdg main
```

Then run:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Finally, run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pgadmin4
```

For more details: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: I've tried something similar and it didn't work, but yours did. I just removed [arch = amd64]. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue... apt.postgresql.org is in the "sources.d", I can see it is "Hit" by "apt update", but still no pgadmin4 installation candidate found.

It looks like focal (20.04) is simply not currently supported (although multiple articles indicate it *was* at one point). Earlier versions are all there. Alas, trying to install them leads to the requirement of python3-psyco2 < 2.8, but 2.8 is the focal version. Perhaps a build fail caused it to drop from repos, or an upstream version change is causing a problem... it's beyond me at this point...

Anyway, I'm not up to working that hard for it... so it's our good old friend "psql" for me right now :-)

Answer (score 3):

As of 21/05/2020 there is no pgAdmin-4 package in Ubuntu 20.04.

Another way to run pgAdmin-4 is by using Docker

```
docker pull dpage/pgadmin4
docker run -p 5050:80 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=XXXX@Xmail.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=thirumal" -d dpage/pgadmin4
```

Then access the pgadmin4 using URL http://localhost:5050 with user name and password.

Docker image URL: https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/

Documentation URL: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html

Full set up guide https://github.com/M-Thirumal/installation_guide/blob/master/pgadmin4/install_pgadmin4_using_docker.md

Answer (score 2):

Check out the discussion [on ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230350/cant-install-pgadmin-4-on-20-04-lts), they explain the issue and how you can work around it. It's because PGAdmin4 lacks support for Python 3.8, as you can see [on Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pgadmin4/).

You'll either need to wait until a compatible release for Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8 is published or work around it by installing PGAdmin in a Python 3.7 environment via something like virtualenv, conda or Docker.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is supported and is available in the focal repo.

Answer (score 0):

While I know it's frustrating when things stop working, I believe version 3 has been back ported. I was able to install it as a test on my 20.04 workstation without any trouble.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve Someone problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use docker-compose by creating a docker-compose.yaml as follows

```
version: '3'

services:
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:80
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=dev@pgadmin.org
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password
```

and running `docker-compose up`.

Make sure you have docker-compose installed if you are going to use this method.